# Проблема в решении задачи по программированию на создание и применение генератора

Tags: python, случайные-числа, генераторы

> Cоздать функцию-генератор, в которую подаётся список и количество
> итераций. Генератор выводит элементы списка со случайными индексами (в
> случайном порядке). Примечание: нельзя выходить за пределы списка;
> понадобится использование функции random.choice() из модуля random.

Моя попытка:

```
from random import choice

lst1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def ran_gen(lst1):
    for i in lst1:
        print(choice(i))
    yield lst1


next(ran_gen(lst1))
```

Прошу не зверствовать в комментариях, я новичок и только осваиваю программирование, поэтому ищу помощи:) Заранее благодарю ответивших!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, должно быть так:

```
lst1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def ran_gen(lst1, count):
    for i in range(count):
        yield choice(lst1)

for i in ran_gen(lst1, 10):
    print (i)
```

Генератор должен возвращать значение, в вашем примере возвращается аргумент, который ему был передан.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: На здоровье! Если ответ решил вашу проблему, стоит отмечать его как решение. Это позволяет другим людям лучше ориентироваться что было нужно когда они вдруг окажутся на этой странице, а также чтобы система не поднимала его впустую как вопрос без решения.